# Why the Lord didn't simply claim that He is God of all in the Torah?

Tags: theology

> I am the Lord, **your** God, who brought you out of the land of Egypt, out of
>   the house of bondage. You shall **have no other gods** before me. You
>   shall not make for yourselves an idol, nor any image of anything that
>   is in the heavens above, or that is in the earth beneath, or that is
>   in the water under the earth: you shall not bow yourself down to them,
>   nor serve them, for I, the Lord your God, am a jealous God, visiting the
>   iniquity of the fathers on the children, on the third and on the
>   fourth generation of those who hate me, and showing loving kindness to
>   thousands of those who love me and keep my commandments.

Few things are suspicious here.

1. The Lord didn't say that he is God of all. He only said that he is the God of Jews.
2. The Lord commands that the Jews (is it appropiate to call them Jews at that time, given that there are more than just Judah tribe?) not to have other gods besides the Lord. The Lord didn't say the other gods do not exist. He said the Jews shouldn't worship other god.

It's like saying star of David is your flag. Though shall not salute other flags (especially those with swastika in it).

What would be the explanation of this so called monotheism?

If Torah describes a supreme "God of all" monotheism, where in the torah it is more explicitly stated?

Note: Basically I am questioning atheists' theory that monotheism arise after Babylonian exile. Hence, any texts after torah that more explicitly declare monotheism don't really "crush" that theory. The topic in this question is in Torah it self.

Answer (score 5):

1) Re: "The LORD didn't say that he is God of all."

- Jeremiah 32:27 'Behold, I am the LORD, the God of all flesh'
- Nehemiah 9:6 'Thou art the LORD, even Thou alone; Thou hast made
  heaven, the heaven of heavens, with all their host, the earth and all
  things that are thereon, the seas and all that is in them, and Thou
  preservest them all; and the host of heaven worshippeth Thee.'

2) Re: "The LORD didn't say the other gods do not exist."

- Samuel 2 7:22   Therefore Thou art great, O LORD GOD; for there is
  none like Thee, neither is there any God beside Thee, according to
  all that we have heard with our ears.
- Isaiah 45:5-6    I am the LORD, and there is none else, beside Me
  there is no God; I have girded thee, though thou hast not known Me;
  That they may know from the rising of the sun, and from the west,
  that there is none beside Me; I am the LORD; and there is none else;

Comment: Also see... All of genesis which was written by Moses

Comment: That's not Torah. That's written long after Torah. Atheist theory is monotheism arise after bible exile. Also no god like Yahweh doesn't mean no other gods. No men is like Jim Thio because I have no biological twin. Are there any other men?

Comment: The Babylonian also said that there is no God like Marduk. Doesn't mean they're monotheist.